# Cancel answer if second to answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If your answer is right, but it's late, should you delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/if-your-answer-is-right-but-its-late-should-you-delete-it)

Imagine I am answering a question and someone else is faster and posts an answer first.
 
With the `1 new answer to the question` notification I can see and read that.

Should I **cancel** my answer if I can't provide a better answer than the just posted one?

Comment: You just leave at any time, or just delete your answer if you've already posted it. It's really up to you.

Comment: Think of it this way: why submit an answer if you can't do better than what's already there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your answer doesn't add any value, there's no harm in canceling.  However, if you do provide additional insights or approaches that may be useful to the asker **or others**, share it!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't necessarily have to be *better*, it can just be different. If you use a different approach to achieve the same effect, you're still being helpful and adding value to the question.

However, if they're fundamentally identical, it's best to either cancel the answer or improve upon it. Multiple answers with the same information can become redundant. If you'd like to verify the correctness of the other answer, give that answer an upvote rather than posting the same information.